# Changhing Highcharts Legend Item Opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have an issue where I can't change the opacity of the Highcharts legends in one of my charts.

I have 5 different legends displaying different values and each legend is represented with a circle and each circle is different color.

Now the issue is that the colors look very faded out and that's because the opacity is set to 20%.

I want to change that to 100% to show the legend color properly. I'm trying to code in CSS but have had no luck and I'm fairly new to CSS. Below is what I have tried to see if this changes the over all opacity...

```
    /*highcharts legends modification for Value Quadrant Portlet*/
.highcharts-legend-item {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

But the above is not working... Below is the HTML code I'm trying to work off of which displays the properties and attributes of the Highcharts legends:

```
<g class="highcharts-legend" zIndex="7" transform="translate(1485,106)">
    <g zIndex="1">
        <g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,3)">
                <text x="21" style="color:#CCC;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;font-
                family:Arial;fill:#CCC;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2" y="14">
                <tspan>1 - Critical
                </tspan>
                </text>
                <circle cx="6" cy="8" r="6" zIndex="3" fill="rgba(237,201,201,0.2)" stroke="#e2e2e2" stroke-width="1">
                </circle>
            </g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,15)">
                <text x="21" y="14" style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;
                font-family:Arial;fill:#000000;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
                    <tspan>2 - High
                    </tspan>
                </text>
                <circle cx="6" cy="8" r="6" zIndex="3" fill="rgba(192,65,28,0.2)" stroke="#e2e2e2" stroke-width="1">
                </circle>
            </g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,27)">
                <text x="21" y="14" style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;
                font-family:Arial;fill:#000000;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
                    <tspan>3 - Moderate
                    </tspan>
                </text>
                <circle cx="6" cy="8" r="6" zIndex="3" fill="rgba(222,102,36,0.2)" stroke="#e2e2e2" stroke-width="1">
                </circle>
            </g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,39)">
                <text x="21" y="14" style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;
                font-family:Arial;fill:#000000;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
                    <tspan>4 - Low
                    </tspan>
                </text>
                <circle cx="6" cy="8" r="6" zIndex="3" fill="rgba(255,202,29,0.2)" stroke="#e2e2e2" stroke-width="1">
                </circle>
            </g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,51)">
                <text x="21" y="14" style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;
                font-family:Arial;fill:#000000;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
                    <tspan>5 - Minimal
                    </tspan>
                </text>
                <circle cx="6" cy="8" r="6" zIndex="3" fill="rgba(44,192,89,0.2)" stroke="#e2e2e2" stroke-width="1">
                </circle>
            </g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(8,63)">
                <text x="21" y="14" style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;
                font-family:Arial;fill:#000000;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
                    <tspan>Default Bucket
                    </tspan>
                </text>
                <circle cx="6" cy="8" r="6" zIndex="3" fill="rgba(225,225,225,0.5)" stroke="#e2e2e2" stroke-width="1">
                </circle>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

The class I pick is highcharts-legend-item but I think each circle attribute would need to be addressed with its properties and color schemes in order to be able to change the opacity on each legend. But I am not sure if that's the way to do and how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated! thanks a lot for looking

Comment: To properly use CSS to style the legend you need to enable the [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.useHTML) option. Otherwise style the elements using the [itemStyle](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemStyle) property.

Comment: shouldn't the colour of your series match the colour of the keys in legend? If you have no problem having the same colour in both places, just set the opacity for the series.

Comment: Could you replicate your exampe as live demo on the jsfiddle.net?